# When making a list from a file, if the file contains more than one value it does not recognise any of the values

Tags: python

I made a program that is supposed to take a list of usernames and passwords from a file. It works perfectly if the files only have one username and password but as soon as I include more than one of them, it does not recognise them at all. Here is the code below.

```
import easygui as e
import os
upper = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
lower = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
loginsystem = True
while loginsystem == True:
    users = []
    file = open("users.secure","r")
    reading = True
    while reading == True:
         tempuser = file.readline()
         if tempuser == "":
            reading = False
        else:
            users.append(tempuser)
    file.close()
    passwords = []
    file = open("passwords.secure","r")
    reading = True
    while reading == True:
        temppassword = file.readline()
        if temppassword == "":
            reading = False
        else:
            passwords.append(temppassword)
    file.close()
    loginmsg = "Enter your username and password"
    logintitle = "Login"
    loginfieldnames = ["Username","Password"]
    loginfieldvalues = []
    login = True
    while login == True:
        loginfieldvalues = 
e.multpasswordbox(loginmsg,logintitle,loginfieldnames)
        while 1:
            if loginfieldvalues == None: break
            loginerrmsg = ""
            for i in range(len(loginfieldnames)):
              if loginfieldvalues[i].strip() == "":
                loginerrmsg = loginerrmsg + ('"%s" is a required field.\n\n' %     loginfieldnames[i])
            if loginerrmsg == "": break
            loginfieldvalues = e.multpasswordbox(loginerrmsg, logintitle, loginfieldnames, loginfieldvalues)
        inputuser = loginfieldvalues[0]
        inputpassword = loginfieldvalues[1]
        if inputuser not in users:
            e.msgbox("Unknown username.",title="Login",ok_button="Try Again")
        else:
            placement = users.index(inputuser)
            if inputpassword != passwords[placement]:
                 e.msgbox("Invalid password.",title="Login",ok_button="Try Again")
             else: login = False
    e.msgbox("Welcome, " + inputuser,title="Login System",ok_button="Continue")
    basicoptions = ["Logout","Quit"]
    running = True
    while running == True:
        choice = e.buttonbox("What would you like to do?",title="Login System",choices=basicoptions)
        if choice == "Quit":
            os._exit(0)
        else:
            running = False
```

The files just contain the word "admin" and when I add another value, I add it onto the next line using "\nadmin2" when writing to the file.

Comment: What do these files look like?

Comment: Exact contents of the files: admin

Comment: Post it in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: It stops reading the files on a blank line. It will not read the whole file if there is a blank line. Is this your intent? The "\nadmin" creates a blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.readline()` will return the newline. That means if you have only one entry, you're likely getting `admin`, but with more lines, you're getting `admin\n`.

Instead you can do:

```
tempuser = file.readline().strip()
```

---

Unrelated to the question, but you can cleanup the code a lot. For example for reading files:

```
def read_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

users = read_file('users.secure')
passwords = read_file('passwords.secure')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. And sorry about my coding, I am new to python as I recently started learning it in school so I haven't been taught much. Ill try use your advice in future programs.

Comment: @PHDBanana Don't apologise for learning :) I'm happy you did.